# HiFi-звучание — через дефис или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Как правильно написать термин **HiFi-звучание** — через дефис или раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Через дефис.

[Вопрос № 292259](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=292259)

> Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужен ли дефис в сочетаниях
>   "indoor реклама" и "outdoor реклама". Если не затруднит, напишите
>   обоснование. Заранее спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Сложные слова, в которых первая часть написана латиницей, обычно
>   пишутся через дефис. Верно: indoor-реклама, outdoor-реклама.

Comment: Здесь проблема в том, что аббревиатура Hi-Fi (=hi-fi) в оригинале пишется через дефис.

Comment: High fidelity (often shortened to **hi-fi** or **hifi**) [Wikipedia]

Comment: Слова с двумя дефисами случаются: экс-премьер-министр, вице-премьер-министр.